# Unity object going through wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

What I've tried and checked:

1. Object has a non-trigger sphere collider
2. Object has `RigidBody`
3. Object has very low mass
4. Object is using Continuous Collision Detection
5. I am adding a low force to the `RigidBody` at `Start`, not `Update`, instead of manually moving every frame
6. Wall has a non-trigger box collider
7. Wall has `RigidBody`
8. Wall is using Continuous Collision Detection

Some other things to note that I don't think the matter is that the object's parent also has a `RigidBody`.

Before this, I was using a `RayCast` to move it out of the ground, but that was causing bugs when it went over inclines, and I would really like it to just work, but for some reason, the ball just goes through inclines, instead of going up them, even after everything else I've tried.

Comment: Is it possible that your sphere of your sphere collider is just not exact enough?

Comment: I don't think so. At this point, I got it to move using `AddForce` every frame, and it hits walls, but it stops on the way up inclines, and I don't know why. I tried rotating the vector that's adding the force, but that didn't go the way I thought.

Comment: Maybe are you in the case in which the wall is thin and the sphere is moving too fast?

Comment: How about [Collision Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)?

Comment: Posting some code could be really helpful.
Also, are you manually telling the ball to ignore certain layers?

Answer (score 0):

~Try this:
in Rigidbody properties, try to change Collision Detection to Continuous instead of discrete. Let me know if that helps.